# Sending variable from JQuery to VB.net using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net

I am trying to send the selection of my autocomplete jquery function into a variable in the back end so i can use a session to grab the string on another page.

```
  <script>

      $(function () {
          var availableTags = [

"a",
"b",
"c",
"d"
    ];
          $("#tags").autocomplete({
              source: availableTags,
              select: function (event, ui) {
                  var selectedItem = ui.item.value;
                  $.get("ProcedureSelectionForm.aspx.vb", {
                        "_functionToRun" : functionToRun,
                        "_selectedVal" : selectedItem
                    },
                        function (returned_data) {
                            console.log(returned_data);
              }
             );
           }
      });
});
  </script>
```

VB: In PHP, I can pass a variable to the backend and grab it with a $_GET['varname']. What is the equivalent in VB?

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitPro.Click
    Session("sent") = _selectedVal
    Response.Redirect("home.aspx")

End Sub
```

Comment: I think that the backend code is not even being called right? You have a set of issues in your code. First thing to do is to call the page it self and not the source code, remove the `.vb` extension...

Comment: thank you i removed the .vb. any guidance you can provide for the backend?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your VB code and check if it has been called.

Comment: Part of my problem is that my JQuery is broken. the autocomplete function populates with a,b,c,d but i cannot actually click them to populate the input box. i was able to do so before i added the select function

Comment: Isolate your problem. First make a direct $.get call and check that  it is correct and it is sucessfully passing the values .